# What are the effects of a machine account being member of Domain Admins?

Tags: windows, active-directory, permissions, domain

I recently stumbled over a workstation account being member of the Domain Admins group. I assume that this is not recommended, right?

Nevertheless, I am curious what the actual effects of this constellation are: does everyone logged on to this machine gain the Domain Admin privilege? Or is it limited to the local SYSTEM, SERVICE, etc. accounts? In other words: how big is the security flaw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Services running with the machine account will gain Domain Admin privileges. Users logged into that machine **will not** inherit such privs. Sometimes this is done if some badly written service that can't run as a user for some reason needs to have access to the entire domain. Also, lazy admins.

As a security flaw it isn't earth-shaking, but it should be resolved. There should be no reason (short of crappy code) for this to be done.

Comment: +1 for lazy admins and crappy code. =)

Comment: Lazy admins +1 ...

Comment: I'm sure the side-effects can be AWESOME.